# Edit More Records at Once with Mass Inline Editing - Winter 18

Tags: opportunity, leads, field-update, update

As per [Winter ’18 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_list_views_mass_inline_edit.htm), there is a provision to update up to 200 records without leaving a list view. The screenshot is showing Opportunity record page but it is not mentioned that it is only available for Opportunity.

Is this feature only available for Opportunity? Is there any permission setting I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shooting in the blind, I have not tested this W18 feature, but it somehow reminds me on the Aloha counterpart mass-edit.

Check if you have different record types on Leads (or whatever Object you want to use this feature). I would not wonder, if the mass-edit work out-of-the-box for Standard an Custom Objects having none or only one RecordType defined and for 2+ RecordTypes to be not available.

If this assumption is correct, try the old Aloha-workaround: make a listview and filter down to a single RecordType. At least in Aloha mass-edit then also kicked in when the listview was used and it worked as expected.

**Edit**

I've just verified that the RecordType limitation is still there:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are absolutely right. The issue was due to multiple Record Types present for the Lead object.  It is working fine when I applied a Record Type filter.

Answer (score 2):

No, I am also able to mass edit on custom objects + standard ones.

[image]

Comment: Can you please check if it is available for Lead also?